# Objective-C - How can I convert Byte Array to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am trying to convert a byte array into a `NSString` object. For testing purposes I am then just trying to print out the contents of the string to the log.

Here's what I got:

```
UInt8 buf[BUFSIZE];
CFIndex bytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(stream, buf, BUFSIZE);
if (bytesRead > 0) {
NSString  *serverText = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buf
                                                 length:(NSUInteger)BUFSIZE
                                               encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog("%@",serverText);
[serverText release];
```

I am trying to initialize a new `NSString` using `initWithBytes` and store this in `serverText`. I can see in the debugger that the value of `serverText` is "invalid address". I am new to objective-c but I assume that means the `initWithBytes` factory method was not successful.

The buffer contains data. Can someone help me out?

Thanks..

Comment: I think that might be the contents of the string.

Comment: the `length:` used in the `init` method should be `bytesRead`, not `BUFSIZE`.

Comment: @Dave DeLong - That's probably not a bad idea. But I still can't figure out how one reads a byte array to string in Cocoa touch /obj-c

Comment: You already figured it out. That's how you do it.

Comment: If initWithBytes:length:encoding: (or alloc) had failed, you'd have had serverTex = nil. If your debugger shows "invalid address" then it's confused — probably you're on a release build and the variable has been aliased onto another, or the debugger is inadvertently trying to report to you before serverText comes into scope.

Answer (score 7):

Here what I came up with:

```
  NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;

            len =  [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buffer maxLength:1024];

            if(len > 0)
            {
                [data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
            }
            NSString *serverText = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithData:data
                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"%@", serverText);
```

Comment: +1 don't forget to `release` your `data` and `serverText` objects.