# Convert binary data to byte array to be transfered via json

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm creating a iphone clients that talks to a wcf service (I do not have control over the server, so no changes can be made here).

I need to send an image to this server, along with some other information. It must be send using json.

I'm using restkit to send and receive data.

The problem is, that the binary data must be send as a byte array. Not as a base64 encoded string.

How do I get from an UIimage to a json string that looks like this

"Picture":{"Content":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..........

I'm open to a solution that doesn't use restkit.

Comment: Can JSON even represent a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type in the receiving WCF service? byte[]?

Sounds hokey, but you could try mapping to an NSNumber realtionship and creating an array of them.

Off the top of my head I think that's going to serialize as:

"Picture":{"Content":["1","1","1".....

So you also might need a custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SO post converting a byte array into an NSString.  If i'm understanding the issue correctly try converting your byte array into the string then adding that to your feed.
[Objective-C - How can I convert Byte Array to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281251/objective-c-how-can-i-convert-byte-array-to-nsstring)

Here's an excerpt of the accepted answer with code:

```
            NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;

            len =  [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buffer maxLength:1024];

            if(len > 0)
            {
                [data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
            }
            NSString *serverText = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithData:data
                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"%@", serverText);
```

Also worth noting once you get the value into your json, watch out that you don't exceed your json max string length value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replys.

Couldn't get any of the suggested answers to work, so we had to use our mad people skills and make the company who made the server side service change their end so we instead can send a base64 encoded string.